# Testing 'create' action of a nested resource with Rspec + FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have searched a lot on the internet as well as other similar questions on Stackoverflow, however I am still not sure on how to test the create method of a nested resource in my rails application.

The resource routes

```
resources :projects, :except => [:index, :show] do
      resources :mastertags
end
```

Here is the action I want to test :

```
 def create
    @mastertag =  @project.mastertags.build(params[:mastertag])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mastertag.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_mastertags_path, notice: 'Mastertag was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my corresponding Rspec test:

```
  context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Mastertag" do
        project = Project.create! valid_attributes[:project]
        mastertag = Mastertag.create! valid_attributes[:mastertag]
        expect {
          post :create, { project_id: project.id, :mastertag => valid_attributes[:mastertag] }
        }.to change(Mastertag, :count).by(1)
      end
  end
```

I have a valid_attributes function as :

```
  def valid_attributes
      { :project => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:project_with_researcher), :mastertag => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:mastertag) }
  end
```

I get the following error :

```
Failure/Error: post :create, { project_id: project.id, :mastertag => valid_attributes[:mastertag] }
NoMethodError:
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for "5168164534b26179f30000a1":String
```

I also tried a couple of variations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will change slightly on your version of FactoryGirl.

The first question is, where is @projet getting created? somewhere else I guess?

You're creating both the project and the mastertag, why are you doing this?

```
project = Project.create! valid_attributes[:project]
mastertag = Mastertag.create! valid_attributes[:mastertag]
```

This is exactly what FactoryGirl does when you call `Factory(:project)` and `Factory(:mastertag)`

The next "wat", is that you create a mastertag in your spec at all. You don't use that variable anywhere. Without fixing your problem, your spec would look a lot better like this:

```
it "creates a new Mastertag" do
  project = Factory(:project)
  expect {
    post :create, { project_id: project.id, :mastertag => Factory.attributes_for(:mastertag)}
  }.to change(Mastertag, :count).by(1)
end
```

Okay, so now that we're done cleaning up the spec, lets look at your error.

Looks like it's in this line

```
format.html { redirect_to project_mastertags_path, notice: 'Mastertag was successfully created.' }
```

This path needs a project id.

```
format.html { redirect_to project_mastertags_path(@project), notice: 'Mastertag was successfully created.' }
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Hinnegan's Answer is absolutely correct. i just want to add that is important, to use on the Project the Id, and not just project:

Sometimes it could be obvious to use project: in the param, but this do not work.

Works:

```
 expect {
      post :create, { project_id: project.id, :mastertag => valid_attributes[:mastertag] }
    }.to change(Mastertag, :count).by(1)
```

Does not work:

```
 expect {
      post :create, { project: project.id, :mastertag => valid_attributes[:mastertag] }
    }.to change(Mastertag, :count).by(1)
```